# Incompatible rank 0 and 1 in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

`ab` is a `4 x 5` matrix i.e., `ab(4,5)` and `x` is an array of length `4` i.e., `x(4)`

```
x(4) = ab(4,5)/ab(4,4)
do i = 3, 1, -1
    x(i) = ( ab(i,5) - ab(i,i+1:4) * x(i+1:4) ) / ab(i,i)
end do
```

The `do` loop says incompatible rank 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you realize that `ab(i,i+1:4)` and `x(i+1:4)` are an array sections?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The manual calculation for `x(3)`, `x(2)` and `x(1)` however works e.g., `x(2) = ( ab(2,5) - ab(2,4) * x(4) - ab(2,3) * x(3) ) / ab(2,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` function in order to reduce the array multiplication to a scalar. i.e. `x(i) = ( ab(i,5) - SUM(ab(i,i+1:4) * x(i+1:4)) ) / ab(i,i)`. Alternatively, the `DOT_PRODUCT` function could be used `DOT_PRODUCT(ab(i,i+1:4) , x(i+1:4))`